# Why can't Emacs get a font that it can list among the fonts?

Tags: fonts

When I list the fonts in my Emacs using the following code:

```
(dolist (font-name (x-list-fonts "*"))
  (let ((str font-name))
    (newline)
    (prin1 str)))
```

One of the fonts I get is:

```
"-outline-SimSun-ExtB-normal-normal-normal-mono-*-*-*-*-c-*-iso10646-1"
```

but when I try to evaluate the following, using [font-spec](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Low_002dLevel-Font.html) and the above font specification:

```
(font-spec :name "-outline-SimSun-ExtB-normal-normal-normal-mono-*-*-*-*-c-*-iso10646-1")
```

Emacs gives the following error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Invalid font name: -outline-SimSun-ExtB-normal-normal-normal-mono-*-*-*-*-c-*-iso10646-1")
  font-spec(:name "-outline-SimSun-ExtB-normal-normal-normal-mono-*-*-*-*-c-*-iso10646-1")
  eval((font-spec :name "-outline-SimSun-ExtB-normal-normal-normal-mono-*-*-*-*-c-*-iso10646-1") nil)
  elisp--eval-last-sexp(t)
  eval-last-sexp(t)
  eval-print-last-sexp(nil)
  funcall-interactively(eval-print-last-sexp nil)
  call-interactively(eval-print-last-sexp nil nil)
  command-execute(eval-print-last-sexp)
```

This is weird, because Emacs complains about a font name being **invalid** that is **obviously in the list** of `(x-list-fonts "*")`.

I mean, I tested it with other values from that list and `font-spec` worked as expected, e.g.

```
(font-spec :name "-outline-SimSun-normal-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-*-iso10646-1")
#<font-spec nil outline SimSun nil iso10646-1 normal normal normal nil nil 0 nil ((:name . "-outline-SimSun-normal-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-*-iso10646-1"))>
```

Why is that?

My Emacs version is 27.0.50, and I'm trying these on MS Windows 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You specify a font in [XLFD-style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_logical_font_description), which normaly consits of 14 parts (specifiers between the `-`).

But your font has 15 parts and this is wrong.
The problem lies here: `SimSun-ExtB`.
I think this should specify the family (`fmly`), but the `-` makes `ExtB` to be evaluated as weight (`wght`) and this is wrong.

To use this font anyway, you could try to specify this font by choosing other parameters for `font-spec`. like `:family`, `:weight`, `:foundry` and so on.
(I can't test this, because I do not have a font with problematic name installed)